# Horror movie with party pranks that turn real

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I am trying to find the name of a horror movie. It is about a girl and her boyfriend who are invited to a party thrown by the girl's sister; the sister does not like the boyfriend and wants to break them up. The party has pranks, people pretending to be killed but then they are actually being killed, and it is the girl and her boyfriend killing them. The house was also from the boyfriend's past, it is where he lived and his family died or were killed. Can anyone help me?

The year was 2002 to 2007, I am not really sure. I saw it years ago on late night TV when I was babysitting, it was in English and no subtitles, so it was probably American. In the first prank, one of the guys goes to get something and then comes back and falls on the floor dead a knife in his back; at first it is just fake but later someone comes back and actually kills him.

Comment: Approximate year? Was it American? Do you remember any specific scenes (like one of the pranks, for example)?

Comment: 2002 to 2007 I am not really sure I saw it years ago on late night tv when I was babysitting, it was in English and no subtitles, so it was probably American. The first prank one of the guys goes to get something and then comes back and falls on the floor dead a knife in his back, at fist it is just fake but later someone comes back and actually kills him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Final Stab](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280672/combined) from 2001.

> Angela's sister wants to get revenge upon her, inviting her to mystery farm along with her old friends, to participate in a game with fake blood and knives - but Angela and her disturbed boyfriend Charlie were not supposed to know about the fake part. But what starts as a little friendly game, gets dark and bloody with real deaths - and sure, real blood and knives.

Angela's sister wants to break up Angela and the disturbed Charlie who witnessed his family's murder. AKA "Final Scream", probably in an attempt to ride the coattails of the successful *Scream* franchise (its bootleg version was [actually called *Scream 4*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0280672/releaseinfo#akas)). Here's the trailer, where you can see the prank with the guy stabbed in his back *[Warning: Slightly Graphic]*: